# Problems with setOnTouchListener CardView & Ripple Effect

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, rippledrawable

When I use `android:foreground` in a `CardView` with `OnTouchListener`, the ripple effect isn't displayed.
Nevertheless in a `CardView` without a touch listener, it works fine!

This is my XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lyt_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false">
```

Comment: Show TouchListener code. I can only guess, but looks like you are returning true from it's onTouch method, so consume touch event, and it is not going to be delivered to CardView, so no ripple effect.